# Difference between vector's Dimensions

Tags: vector, vector-calculus

What's the difference between

```
projection= Table[Conjugate[autoVett[[k]].someVector1], {k, 1, r}]
Dimensions[projection]
```

that gave me as results `{12}` which is ok.

```
Dimensions[baseComp]
{8}
Dimensions[Transpose[{baseVector}]]
{12,1}
startState = 
  KroneckerProduct[baseComp, Transpose[{baseVector}]] ;
Dimensions[startState]
{96,1}
scompoStartState = 
  Table[Conjugate[CCNOTHvec[[k]].startState], {k, 1, 
    Length[CCNOTHvec]}];
Dimensions[scompoStartState]
{96,1}
```

What's the difference between a `{12}` vector and a `{96,1}` vector?
I need to have just 96-dimensional vector.

Comment: What's the difference between autoVett[[k]], someVector1, baseComp[[4]], and someVector2?

Comment: they are both {n} dimensional vector..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kronecker product of two vectors of sizes $n$ and $m$ always gives a matrix of size $n$ by $m$. For example:

```
a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 4];
b = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 5]; 
Dimensions[KroneckerProduct[a, b]]
```

In fact, the `KroneckerProduct` is just a rewriting of

```
Outer[Times, a, b]
```

and this same calculation can also be done with `Table`

```
Table[a[[i]] b[[j]], {i, 1, Length[a]}, {j, 1, Length[b]}]
```

all of which give the same $n=4$ by $m=5$ matrix. You can turn any of the above into a vector using `Flatten`. Hence

```
Flatten[Outer[Times,a,b]]
```

is a vector of size $4\times 5=20$ containing the same elements as the 4 by 5 matrix.

Comment: I know, but I want to have a 5*4 vector, not a matrix.
eg:
Command[{a,b},{c,d}] = {a*c, a*d, b*c, b*d}

Comment: See change... `Flatten[Outer[Times, {a, b}, {c, d}]]` gives what you ask for (make sure to `Clear` a,b,c,d so the values don't conflict.)